# Printing results of a NodeJS web request to the screen

Tags: node.js, request

I have the following NodeJS request:

```
var request = require('request');
var test_headers = {
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36", 
    "Referer": "https://test", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Content-Length": "2"
}

var test_options = {
    url: "https://test?&test=#,&tester2=",
    headers: test_headers,
    method: "get",
}
request(test_options)
```

I can intercept it with a proxy and see that the request is outgoing successfully, but I haven't been able to get it to print to the screen. I've tried printing the contents of request, as well as querying. I'm sure it's something basic, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var request = require('request');
var test_headers = {
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36", 
    "Referer": "https://test", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Content-Length": "2"
}

var test_options = {
    url: "https://test?&test=#,&tester2=",
    headers: test_headers,
    method: "get",
}
console.log('Requesting..');
request(test_options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```